# Proofs of simple arithmetic expressions

Tags: coq, proof

I would like to prove a bunch of theorems like 100 + 100 = 200 or 1 > - / 2 in real numbers, but I it seems like coq can't do this using auto tactic. Is there any way to prove thing like this without writing hundreds of lines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ring` will prove equalities
`lra` and `nra` will prove basic comparisons
`interval` will prove comparisons involving advanced functions and constants (`sin`, `PI`, `exp`).  `lra` are available in Coq without installing extensions.  `interval` requires an extension to be installed (`coq-interval` in the `opam` package index).  Some pre-packaged installation of Coq already include `interval`.

```
Require Import Reals Lra Interval.Tactic.
Open Scope R_scope.

Lemma examples : 100 + 100 = 200 /\ 2 ^ 19 < 3 ^12 /\ 3.14 <= PI <= 3.15.
split.
(* your need. *)
ring.
split.
(* simpl comparison between constants (algebraic formulas). *)
lra.
(* advanced comparison between constants *)
interval.
Qed.
```

At the time of writing the first version of the answer, I was a little disappointed because `interval` only handled `<=` and not `<` .

Comment: FWIW, recent versions of `interval` can also prove strict inequalities such as `3.14 < PI < 3.15`

Comment: I tried again today (May 23, 2022), and with the opam available version of coq-interval `4.5.1` it still does not accept strict inequalities.

Comment: Well in fact the goal `3.14 < PI < 3.15` is not solved in one go by `interval`, but the two goals `3.14 < PI` and `PI < 3.15` are.  This is still a bit disappointing.